# Quote from book

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just read in a book the following dialogue:

"'Two negatives make a positive, am I correct?' Andret smiled. 'You are indeed. At least for operations in which the identity element is *one*.'"

Anyone care to elaborate as to why this is true?

Comment: Could "operations in which..." just be an elaborate way to say multiplication? Taken literally it's not true; under the operation $x\oplus y=x+y-1$, $\mathbb R$ is a group with identity $1$, yet $(-1)\oplus(-1)=-3$.

Comment: @stewbasic It's an amateur math nerd's joke, so can't fault them too much. I agree it's meant to indicate multiplication.

Comment: That is a misleading statement for any reader other than one who *already* knows the exact meaning. It is misleading because it seems we're talking about *one* operation (at a time). If there were only one operation, then the negation is inversion with respect to that operation. In that case, either it **is not** true: $a^{-1} * b^{-1} \ne a * b$ (in general); or it **is** true in a way that is clearly not the intended one: $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ [this is not the intended meaning, for this works even when the identity is not "one": $-(-a) = a$].

Comment: The intended meaning is that there are *two* operations: $+$ and $*$, where negation is defined with respect to $+$ and the identity for $*$ is $1$. Then, $(-a)*(-b) = a*b$, but **only with some more assumptions on $+$ and $*$**.

Comment: Thank you all for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Oh, and even the terms "negative" and "positive" have to be interpreted in a particular way. For example: $(-i) \times (-i) = -1$ [though of course, it's still true that $(-i) \times (-i) = +i^2$]. The problem here is that the complex numbers do not form an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field).